# Change step between ticks with plotly

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I have the following code

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 20), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys")
p
```

[image]

Is there anyway to change to steps between the ticks on the y-axis to display only the even numbers (0, 2, 4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify some of the `layout.yaxis.tick*` attributes. You can read more about it [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-tickmode) to see further customisation options.

```
library(plotly)
A <- matrix(seq(1, 20), nrow = 4, ncol = 5)
p <- plot_ly(z = t(A), type = "heatmap", colorscale = "Greys")
p %>% layout(
  yaxis = list(
    tickmode = 'array', 
    tickvals = seq(0, 5, by = 2), 
    ticktext = seq(0, 5, by = 2)
  )
)
```

[image]